# If $a,b \in \mathbb R$, prove that the equation $z^3=a+bi$ has at least one complex solution

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> If $a,b \in \mathbb R$, prove that the equation $z^3=a+bi$ has at least one complex solution.

It seem to me pretty obvious that this equation has 3 complex roots and they are $\sqrt[3]{a+bi}$, $(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}} \sqrt[3]{a+bi}$ and $(-1)^{\frac{4}{3}} \sqrt[3]{a+bi}$ and they're all complex. So that's the whole solution? I would love to have strict proof of this.

Comment: That's how I read the problem too: "Prove that any complex number actually has at least one complex cube root." Besides, it has only one solution if $a=b=0$, so there aren't _always_ three.

Comment: Take $b=0$ and "they're all complex" becomes wrong

Comment: Is $\sqrt[3]{}$ actually a meaningful function on complex numbers? If you already know that to be true, then that is a satisfactory answer (at least, when paired with the fact its value is actually a cube root). The point of this question, presumably, is to ask you to establish the fact that $\sqrt[3]{}$ is a meaningful function.

Comment: @ThePortakal: $1$ is a complex number.

Comment: @Hurkyl oh my mistake, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the goal of the problem is to give an *elementary* proof of the fact that any complex number has at least one cubic root. In your solution, you write $\sqrt[3]{a+bi}$, but isn't this what we want to prove?

Maybe you can say: every real number has at least one real cubic root (Bolzano's Theorem) and every complex number with modulo $1$ is of the form $e^{\alpha i}$, hence has also at least one complex cubic root, namely $e^{\frac{\alpha}{3}i}$. Now any $z\in \mathbb{C}$ can be written as $re^{\alpha i}$ for some $r, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, and therefore we can find at least one complex cubic root of $z$ by finding one for $r$, one for $e^{\alpha i}$ and then multiplying them.